# Motor works on 9V battery but not 9V power supply

Tags: voltage, batteries, amperage

I had a motor that was working on a 9 V battery

I now want to connect it to a charger that has 9 V output.
When I connect the motor to the 9 V charger sparkles poop out.

The charger is rated at 1.5A, is this too much for this motor?
I cant find the current rating of the 9 V battery. The battery is a 'Krona' brand battery.

What can I do to get the motor to work from the 9 V charger?

Comment: What type of motor it is? Can you add some photo, or datasheet?

Comment: Do you have a 5V power source you can use? Chop up an old unwanted USB phone charger cable and use that, if it doesn't run well on 9V its most likely due to the charger putting out to much current, as previously mentioned batteries can't put out that much current where as a charger can.

Comment: @Alex Whilst your suggestion _might be_ correct (You're assuming it's a 5V motor when it could be 1.5V or 3V) your thinking is a little bit off. It doesn't fail because the 9 V charger has a higher current value. Imagine if you replace the motor with a fixed resistor, if the voltage increases then the resistor (motor) will have more current flowing through it. This is essentially what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Art of Electronics, "A standard 9 volt battery behaves approximately liike a perfect 9 volt voltage source in series with a 3Ω resistor, and it can provide a maximum current (when shorted) of 3 amps (which, however will kill the battery in a few minutes). So no the supplies are not the same, the 9V battery can supply more current.

But that is not the problem. The motor would have to be a brushed DC motor for it to operate under a DC current. Unless your motor has an insane internal friction or torque, it should turn at lower RPM even when ran at low current.

Answer (score 5):

If it runs on a 9Volt battery, but does crazy things on a 9Volt power supply, then it likelyis not meant for use on 9Volts.

A lower voltage motor might run OK on 9Volts because a 9Volt battery can't supply much current - the voltage drops when the motor tries to draw a lot of current.

With a powersupply that can provide lots of current at 9Volts, the motor will try to draw lots of current - and it will get it.  A motor made for lower voltage may then run crazy fast and/or spray sparks and/or burn out.

Find out what voltage the motor is rated for. Small motors for toys typically run on 1.5Volts or 3Volts (two 1.5V cells in series.)